# Dual vector space problem for continuous complex functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X:= C([-1,1],\mathbb{C})$ a Banach space of complex and continuous functions with the following norm, $||x||_{C[-1,1]}=\max_{t \in [-1,1]}|x(t)|$. Now I have the following functional, $$\lambda(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-x(0) \hspace{1 cm} , \hspace{1 cm} x\in X $$ Now the idea is to be able to conclude that $X$ is not reflexive. For that I know that I need to demonstrate first that $\lambda \in X^{*}$ ($X^{*}$ being the dual space of $X$) and then find $||\lambda||_{X^{*}}$. And then I suppose I have to prove that James' theorem hypothesis aren't achieved (i.e it doesn't exist $x \in X, x\neq 0$ so $|\lambda (x)|=||\lambda (x)||_{X^{*}}||x||_{X}$). I know that $X$ is a compact space and what are the steps to follow I just don't know how to start and how to connect those steps (it's kind of the idea of the problem I know). But I've been almost three days and I only have the main idea of what to do. I'm not asking for a beautiful solution of the problem (although that would be great), some useful tips are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to see that $|\lambda(x)|\leq3\|x\|$. Now use a sequence of mollifiers $(x_n)$ of the constant $1$ function with $x_n(0)=-1$ in order to show that $\|\lambda\|=3$. For example, consider the functions
\begin{align}
x_n(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}1&:&t\in[-1,-\frac{1}{n}]\cup[\frac{1}{n},1]\\
-2nx-1&:&t\in(-\frac{1}{n},0]\\
2nx-1&:&t\in(0,\frac{1}{n}]\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Now to show that there is no $x\in C([-1,1])$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that $|\lambda(x)|=3$, assume there is.  Then you have to show a few things:

$(1)$: $\left|\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt\right|=2$ and $|x(0)|=1$. This comes from the geometry of $\mathbb C$. Then assume without loss of generality that $x(0)=1$.

$(2)$: $\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt=\text{Re}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt\right)=-2$. This follows the same general line as the first, using the geometry of $\mathbb C$.

$(3)$: $x(t)=-1$ for all $t\in[-1,1]$.  Here's your contradiction.